Edit debconf/config.dat File
I have the following in /var/cache/debconf/config.dat:
Name: grub-efi/install_devices
Template: grub-efi/install_devices
Value: /dev/sda1
Owners: grub-common, grub-efi-amd64, grub-pc
Flags: seen
Variables:
CHOICES:
RAW_CHOICES

Name: grub-efi/install_devices_disks_changed
Template: grub-efi/install_devices_disks_changed
Value: /dev/sda1, /dev/sdb1
Owners: grub-common, grub-efi-amd64,
Flags: seen
Variables:
CHOICES:
RAW_CHOICES

I need to change the Value of 'install_devices' to '/dev/sdb1'.
What is the best way of doing this? I've read that just editing config.dat isn't the best way to do it.
Will 'dpkg-reconfigure grub-efi-amd64/grub-common' fix this? That won't fix grub-pc though?
How about debconf-set-selections?
Thanks.

Solution was this:
echo "grub-efi-amd64 grub-efi/install_devices multiselect /dev/sdc1" | debconf-set-selections

